# Convert python ordinal date to normal date in Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, date

Is there any way to convert a 6-digit ordinal date (days since January 1, 0001 AD) to a normal timestamp in Postgres? Date is created using python's datetime.toordinal().

For example,

```
>>> date = datetime.date(2010, 7, 20)
>>> datetime.toordinal(date)
733973
```

What I need is to convert '733973' back to '2010-07-20' in Postgres.

Thanks!

Comment: A julian date is based on January 1, 4713 BC;

Comment: Postgresql's Julian day is actually based on Midnight November 24, 4714 BC.  See documentation http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what first came to my mind:

```
select date (date '0000-12-31' + interval '733973 days');
>> "2010-07-20"
```

or

```
select date (date '0000-12-31' + interval '1 days' * 733973);
>> "2010-07-20"
```

It simply adds the number of days to the date `0000-12-31`. It doesn't use the date `0001-01-01`, as `datetime.toordinal()` is defined to be `1` for this date, hence the -1 offset.

From the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html)

> **date.fromordinal(ordinal)**
>       Return the date corresponding to the proleptic Gregorian ordinal, where
>   January 1 of year 1 has ordinal 1...

### Edit:

If the date `0000-31-12` is not recognised as a valid date, you can easily change the statement to something like:

```
select date (date '0001-01-01' + interval '733973 days' - interval '1 day');
```

or

```
select date (date '0001-01-01' + (interval '1 days' * (733973 - 1)));
```

Comment: This seems to work. The only problem is using '0000-12-31' returns en error `ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "0000-12-31"`. I have to use 0001-12-31 and the substract one year.... any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: this works on my PotsgreSQL 8.3 installation. What data base do you use? As an alternative use: `select date (date '0000-12-31' + interval '733973 days' - interval '1 day');`

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL 8.4 I'm using:

```
to_date(2455452::text, 'J')
```

The '0000-12-31'::date trick above worked up to PG 8.3 but produces the mentioned error with PG 8.4 (and higher I believe). PG 8.4 also requires both arguments of to_date(text, text) to be of type text, that's the reason for casting the Julian date values to text.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

http://doxygen.postgresql.org/backend_2utils_2adt_2timestamp_8c-source.html

Look at line 01416:

```
j2date((int) date, &tm->tm_year, &tm->tm_mon, &tm->tm_mday);
```

More on j2date function...

[PostgreSQL binary timestamp functions](http://blog.stranadurakov.com/2009/05/21/postgresql-binary-timestamp-functions/)

[Project of UDF and its realization at C for PostgreSQL](http://www.pgsql.cz/index.php/Project_of_UDF_and_its_realization_at_C_for_PostgreSQL)